# WP8 emulator not running on windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-10, hyper-v

I'm trying to build an application for windows phone 8 on visual studio 2012 using windows 10 pro - 64-bit.
WP8 SDK with last update and VS2012 update 4 have been installed.

An error appear when i run app:

[image: Wp emulator]

also an error appear on console: 0x80131500

I checked the hyper-v, and nothing relate to WP8 emulator was there!: 
[image: Hyper-v]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to make sure the Hyper V service is installed and turn on.

[How to Setup and Use Hyper-V in Windows 10 for OS Virtualization](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a.html)

Pay attention when it comes to enabling the service with this picture.

[image: Turn On Hyper-V]

I'm pretty sure a computer reboot is required.  If that still doesn't work for you then you have something conflicting with HYPER-V or your hardware does not support it.

I know VM Ware does not play nicely with HYPER-V turn on and vice versa, so you might want to build a separate computer for your Windows Phone development like I did, if you run VM Ware Player or Workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i encounter the same problem, it turns out that you have to install windows phone 8.1 sdk in order to run windows phone 8 app unter windows 10. Surprised ?... me neither :D

Comment: This message appear when i'm trying to install WP8.1 SDK: "This computer does not support the WP emulator, which requires the 64-bit edition pf windows 8.1 Pro and a computer that supports Hyper-V" ..

Comment: So you have VS2012 right,  create a new windwos phone 8 project, than try to run the emulator, this will fail but it will pop a message, download the sdk from that link

Comment: This is the link that i get from the pop message: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx .. nothing relate to wp8.1 sdk !

Comment: This is that i used !

Answer (score 0):

In the last updates of Windows 10, is possible that MS pushed one to prevent using the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK (the one that uses VS2012). My recommendation: create a Virtual Machine in VMware with Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 and install the SDK.